# T-SQL buffered output

Tags: t-sql

I have a T-SQL script that I run as needed to delete old history records from a SQL 2019 database. There are associated records in other tables that need to go as well, so altogether I typically delete around 100 million records altogether.

My script is based on Brent Ozar's example that uses Views (many thanks!) and so I delete 1 million record chunks in a loop until there aren't any left. I would like to monitor progress in real time in SSMS (which is fully up to date), but the Print statements get buffered and then several appear at once. Raiserror behaves in exactly the same way. I have even redirected Print output to a text file, but that is no different.

Is there any way of seeing each progress statement when it is created?

Comment: Did you use the `NOWAIT` option with [raiserror](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments)?

Comment: @dondon841, Another option is to run  a `SELECT` to your table with `NOLOCK` option to view the data

Comment: Thanks. I didn't have either of these - I will give them a try.